# Inheriting Modified DNA after CRISPR editing

Tags: genetics, molecular-genetics, crispr

If CRISPR is used to modify the DNA sequence to cure a disease - say MS in a woman - will the RNA guides also modify the sequence in her eggs so her children could be born without MS inherited from her.

Answer (score 1):

First off, CRISPR can't be used to cure diseases in an adult human or, more generally, for any adult vertebrate at present.

As you can see in [this paper](http://www.nature.com/nrd/journal/v16/n2/full/nrd.2016.238.html), a major problem with CRISPR is it has to target specific cell types in tissues. As long as the targets are somatic and not germline, the edits made by CRISPR will not be heritable.